# How to trigger a "select" event on a LI, identified by it's ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have menu like this:

```
<ol id="list" class="juilist ui-selectable" style="float: left;">

<li class="ui-widget-content" id="task_27">ay</li>
<li class="ui-widget-content" id="task_28">b</li>
</ol>
```

I would like to triggger a 'select' event on a specified ID as follows, with jQuery:

```
 trigger(select(id="task_27"))
```

I am quite new to jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bind a `select` event handler to those li elements, you can simply trigger that select event afterwards.

```
$('li.ui-widget-content').on('select', function(){
    // code handling what happens when selected
});
```

Then, simply trigger that event on the desired element:

```
$('#task_27').trigger('select');
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to trigger the click event

```
$('#task_27').click() //or  $('#task_27').trigger('click')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#task_27').trigger('click') //or
$('#task_27').trigger('select');//or
$('#task_27').click()
```